# Django - JSON file to DTL and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am trying to read a JSON file and pass its content to my template like this:

```
with open('Directory_To_Json', "r") as data:
        content = json.load(data)
        return render(request, 'Displayer/index.html', {'Content': content})
```

It works, but I also want to be able to work with the same JSON inside of my javascript. I tried it like this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse("{{Content}}");
```

But there is an error at the second position, although the JSON itself is valid. (I tried adding the "safe" modifier as well)

I guess it's because I pass it the json.load output, which is formated to work with Python. But how can I pass it the raw json file content?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**json.load()** returns a dictionary. You can convert a dictionary to a JSON string using **json.dumps()**
Try this:

```
 with open('Directory_To_Json', "r") as data:
    myjson = json.load(data)
    content = json.dumps(myjson)
    return render(request, 'Displayer/index.html', {'Content': content})
```